# How to remain keyboard after Done click on EditText in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have some app with EditText.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_game_word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true" > 

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

When I click Done button on the keyboard, the one hides, but I want to remain keyboard after clicking. Keyboard must be hide only pressing Back button. I tried to add InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED to continue showing keyboard, but this doesn't work.

```
editTextWord.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                someCode();
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Activity's softInputMode in your manifest to always display the soft input keyboard via android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" or should it only be visible after opening that specific EditText?

Comment: I tried put android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" in my activity, but after Done click keyboard hides. No specific EditText, I have only one EditText.